# C# Speech Recognition Engine Innacurate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, speech-recognition

Below is the speech recognition code I have.  I've noticed that its not that good at picking up sentences.  Is there something I can do to fix this?

```
public String listenForVoice() {
   SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
   Grammar dictationGrammar = new DictationGrammar();
   recognizer.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);
   try
   {
       recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
       RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();
       return result.Text;
   } catch (InvalidOperationException exception) { }
   finally {
      recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();
   }
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:**
To improve the accuracy of Speech Recognition Engine try to create and load grammar that is similar to the word/grammar/speech you want to use. This way we can improve the accuracy.

**Second:**
Evaluate hypothesized trigger 1, trigger 2 and then recognized confidence levels and results. This is not practical as this would be different for each person/user.

There is no way to prevent the .NET Speech Recognition Engine from ALWAYS RETURNING A GRAMMAR MATCH. You may as well be saying "bob" in a silent room into a studio grade mic and it would recognize "open windows media player". lol

*Warning 1: grammar word lists of over 1,000 slow things down and can lock the application.*

*Warning 2: en-US has good English recognition capabilities, switching to en-GB etc lowers accuracy drastically*

So far with **Googles Speech Recognition API** (does require you to be online) but it is 10x more accurate and you can easily test for a match yourself.

Comment: I am using it as a Speech to Text program.  I'm not trying to do commands.  But an aided STT.

Comment: Thanks for more info, will get back